# Changing the size of the Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is there a way to change the size of the Windows 7 Taskbar ?I'm fine with built in solutions or third party software. Something like the MacOS X Doc Zooming effect would be OK/nice, too.

**Edit:**
I'm essentially looking for a way to shrink it, because my laptop does not have a big screen so every pixel is valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I did some digging...

- In the [suggested question](https://superuser.com/questions/32255/good-dock-app) by
  Snark, there was a mention of [Object
  Dock](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/), which seems like a cool
  MacOS X Dock replacement for Windows.
  Officially it does not seem to
  support Windows 7, yet... But in the
  [forums](http://forums.stardock.com/350544) there are mentions of
  getting it to work.
- Then you can obviously increase the
  size as [suggested by Snark](https://superuser.com/questions/66611/changing-the-size-of-the-windows-7-taskbar/66613#66613). But
  I was looking for a way to shrink it.
  I didn't quite make that clear in my
  question, sorry for that.
- There is one way to shrink it a
  little, as it turns out: [Choose
  small icon size.](http://malektips.com/windows-7-shrink-taskbar-size.html)
- Another good way to get back screen
  real estate is to turn on
  [Autohide.](http://malektips.com/windows-7-taskbar-hide.html) I guess that's what I
  will use.
- I just found another way... which might be a little extrem: Totally [eliminate](https://superuser.com/questions/66473/is-there-any-way-to-delete-the-windows-7-taskbar/66482#66482) the taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the Taskbar, uncheck Lock the taskbar.
You can increase its height by grabbing its side and dragging it up.

For the zooming effect, not possible by default, unless you replace the taskbar with an alternative dock. There are some suggestions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/32255/good-dock-app). LifeHacker has also a [list of application docks](http://lifehacker.com/5394449/five-best-application-docks).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this is relevant for you, but I could not shrink the width as narrow as I wanted until I removed some 3rd party tools from the taskbar (Thinkpad stuff: AccessConnections etc). Once I had removed them, I could drag the edge much thinner.

Answer (score 0):

Shark's solution kind of worked for me, but make sure you also use small icons for your taskbar.

1. Right click start
2. Click properties
3. Click the taskbar tab
4. Check use small icons
5. Right click the taskbar, and make sure "lock the taskbar is off"
6. Drag the taskbar down to your preferred size.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to removed custom toolbar (shortcut to folder) from taskbar with these steps:

Right click on taskbar and from menu, select **Properties**, select **Toolbars** tab and uncheck all toolbars (see the screenshot).

[image]

and then it is possible to resize the taskbar. If you want, you can restore removed toolbar after resizing.